# contact ID input via VF to flow

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

[image]I'm trying to rewrite the task creation process with flow. And the code below is used to pass account id to my flow so that the field "Related to" can be fulfilled. However, the field called Name as I've pointed out in the screenshot cannot be input a value now because the id actually comes from contact.

for my org, I've been using person account, I know the contact will be auto created behind the scene when I create the account. So, here is the question, is there any way I can modify the code below to pass a related contact id to my flow?

Thanks

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
  <flow:interview name="Orientation_Call" finishLocation="/{!Account.Id}">
      <apex:param name="AccountId" value="{!Account.Id}"/>
  </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can assign the `PersonContactId` field to your input variable. The general modification would look like this:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
  <flow:interview name="Orientation_Call" finishLocation="/{!Account.Id}">
      <apex:param name="AccountId" value="{!Account.Id}"/>
      <apex:param name="WhoId" value="{!Account.PersonContactId}"/>
  </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks Fox, and I have more question about the parameter. Cuz I've assigned the record ID to the variable call AccountId in my flow, If I used WhoId as the parameter, which means I need to assign contact ID to it, but there is no more variable I can refer to. I just added another screenshot to my question, feel free to check it out. Thanks again.

Comment: @JetCai The record Id you're assigning to AccountId is the task's ID after its creation (which you don't want to do). You need to create some new variables.

Comment: Bravo Fox! I just made it happen by creating another new variable in the flow. Thanks a lot man.